# Migrating from D3.js v4 to D3.js v7 not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, d3.js

I want to attempt to convert this force from D3 v4 to v7, but not sure how to go about it.The code conversion what I have done is here.
I try to do this< [https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide>](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide%3E)

D3 6.0 is out! It comes with exciting new features and improvements.

It also introduces a few important API changes. But, do not fear: almost all the methods are behaving exactly as they did with v5; just a handful of them are not backwards compatible.

Here's a comprehensive list of the changes you will need to watch for when you upgrade to D3 v6:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

</style>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<script>

const svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/3, height / 3));

d3.json("helpme.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  const link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d[2])*2; });

  const node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")

  const circles = node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("fill", "olive");

  // Create a drag handler and append it to the node object instead
  const drag_handler = d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended);

  drag_handler(node);
  
  const lables = node.append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      })
      .attr('x', 6)
      .attr('y', 3);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        })
  }
});

  
function dragstarted(event,d) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(event,d) {
  d.fx = event.x;
  d.fy = event.y;
}

function dragended(event,d) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
```

helpme.json

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "A"},
    {"id": "B"},
    {"id": "C"},
    {"id": "D"},
    {"id": "E"},
    {"id": "F"}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "C", "target": "B", "value": 2},
    {"source": "C", "target": "D", "value": 3},
    {"source": "D", "target": "A", "value": 1},
    {"source": "D", "target": "E", "value": 1},
    {"source": "E", "target": "F", "value": 1},
    {"source": "F", "target": "B", "value": 4}
  ]
}
```

Can someone please help me fix this?Some assistance would be amazing!
Danke in Voraus

Comment: The only thing that jumps out to me is `d3.json("helpme.json", function(error, graph) { ...` should be `d3.json("helpme.json").then(function(graph) { ...` which was a change in d3v5 I believe.

Comment: I really appreciate the guidance and help

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at their full migration guide:
https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/CHANGES.md

I would recommend going major by major.

Comment: I'll just add one more detail on this answer, don't upgrade to v7 directly, just upgrade to the next version. if that is done and successful do upgrade to the next one and so on. Notice what you are using from the library and cross it with the migration guide to see how it changed and apply the changes accordingly. I had the same problem and had to do alot of switching on the codebase in order to upgrade. even afterwards I was keeping an eye on anything that is not working as usual and crossing it with the upgrade in case it was the reason behind it. Long story short, use the migration guide.